# How to update from Gazebo2 to Gazebo3?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:

Under the following link I tried to update Gazebo2

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

But the hyperlink of these instruction under the following description does not found any update related information.

How can I update to Gazebo3 ?

Indigo uses Gazebo 2 which is the default version of Gazebo on Trusty and is recommended. If you need to upgrade to Gazebo 3 see these instructions about how to upgrade the simulator.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246642/how-to-update-from-gazebo2-to-gazebo3-?/) by [PaulTsai111](https://answers.ros.org/users/28338/paultsai111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That link should probably point to [Which combination of ROS/Gazebo versions to use](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions) on the Gazebo tutorials site instead.

---

Edit: I've fixed the link and updated the wiki text to mention Gazebo 5, 6 and 7.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PaulTsai111](https://answers.ros.org/users/28338/paultsai111/) on 2016-10-28**:
After entering the web site mentioned above, and found this site is where I can download
http://packages.ros.org/ for Gazebo2.x(Indigo ROS)
However, I can not found the Gazebo2.x . Can you show me where and how can I get this file ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
I don't really understand what you're trying to say. You shouldn't manually download anything, but have your package manager install the pkgs for you.

Do you want to install Gazebo 2, or some newer version?